# Replacing Provider injections with Mockito mocks during test with Dagger

Tags: android, android-testing, dagger

I am attempting to test-drive a suite of changes I'm making to my Android service (`android.app.Service`) - I am using Dagger and Robolectric and I need to replace the field injected classes within the service with some mocks to reduce the test scope...make it (slightly) more 'unit' like.

### So, the short version...

I inject `Providers.of` (Guice syntax there...) into my `android.app.Service`. How do I replace them with MockProviders during a unit test?

### The longer version...

This is what the relevant service code looks like;

```
@Inject SpotService spotService;
@Inject Provider<SynchroniseTidePosition> syncTidePosition;
@Inject Provider<SynchroniseSwellDataTask> syncBuoyData;
@Inject Provider<SynchroniseConditionsTask> syncConditionsData;
@Inject SpotRatingCalculator spotRatingCalculator;
@Inject LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;
@Inject NotificationManager notificationManager;

/**
 * @see android.app.Service#onCreate()
 */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  inject(this);
...
```

So, under normal operation the `startService(intent)` call lets the service inject it's dependencies during `onCreate` and we're all good.

Under my test I want to replace the injected `Provider`s `get()` calls with Mockito mocks. I have attempted to follow the [Dagger test example](http://square.github.io/dagger/) and created a test module that looks like this;

```
@Module(includes = OceanLifeModule.class,
        injects = {TestSynchronisationServiceNotifications.class},
        overrides = true)
  static class TestSynchronisationServiceNotificationsModule {
    @Provides LocalBroadcastManager provideLocalBroadcastManager() {
      return LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Robolectric.application);
    }
    
    @Provides NotificationManager providesNotificationManager() {
      return (NotificationManager) Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    
    @Provides SpotService provideSpotService() {
      return mock(SpotService.class);
    }
    
    @Provides SpotRatingCalculator provideSpotRatingCalculator() {
      return mock(SpotRatingCalculator.class);
    }
    
    @Provides SynchroniseTidePosition provideSyncTidePosition() {
      return mock(SynchroniseTidePosition.class);
    }
    
    @Provides SynchroniseConditionsTask provideSyncConditionsTask() {
      return mock(SynchroniseConditionsTask.class);
    }
    
    @Provides SynchroniseSwellDataTask provideSyncSwellDataTask() {
      return mock(SynchroniseSwellDataTask.class);
    }
  }
```

I am expecting that when my actual Service code calls the Provider `get()` I would be getting the *Mockito* mocks back (those are the mocks that my test module @Provides).

This isn't happening. What's wrong with the approach I'm heading down here?

Comment: Can you share also your inject() method?

Comment: Hi Eugen. The inject method resides under my ````Application```` subclass and follows a familiar pattern of;

public static <T> void inject(final T instance) { objectGraph.inject(instance) }

I can confirm that the 'simple' injections (SpotService in this example) are having their implementations overridden with the Mockito mocks. Just the providers have me stumped.

Comment: Interesting. Because in my project I had to inject Module to app explicitly. I didn't know that it can be done automatically at least for 'simple' injections

Comment: Could it be that onCreate called by Robolectric after you do injection in setUp for test or wise versa?

Comment: I've taken control of the service set-up implementing a "ServiceController" which has a similar API to the Robolectric.buildActivity methods. So robolectric isn't being leveraged directly here apart from (hopefully) later when I inspect the Notifications generated. Here is the full test: http://pastebin.com/535u1PBC

Comment: It's more clear. As I asked (just to be sure) -`serviceController.withIntent(synchronisationService).start();` - is this guy will call onCreate (which will call inject) for Service?

Comment: Ah..I think you are on to something. Indeed that line should read .create().start(). When I change it to that (to call the onCreate as intended) the inject method overrides the bindings provided by my test Module...crap(!) - I must have dropped the ````create()```` call out when I was tweaking the set-up. Why does the main application inject method respect the module bindings? This must be what you were alluding to in your initial comment _cf. inject Module to app explicitly_... thoughts?

Comment: Great! Because Activities will do injection in onCreate and they operate with Application I had to inject module to Application itself. Which is not nice from architecture design

Answer (score 3):

Make your own `Providers.of()`:

```
public static <T> Provider<T> of(final T t) {
  return new Provider<T>() {
    public T get() {
      return t;
     }
  }
}
```

Dagger should probably include this in a testing module.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer Jesse. From my discussion with Eugen above it is clear that my test module is working fine. However, it is my service _inject_ method which is sending things awry. Up until _inject_ is called under my app code, the mocks hold strong. After the inject the mocks are replaced with the real things. It seems the scope (?) of module graph built under the Service described is incorrect? Do you have any advice in how to avoid this scenario? (i.e. where the main app inject methods 'win' over the test modules)